# Google Document Viewer shows: the server cannot process the request because it is malformed

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, blob, preview, viewer

I try to preview the documents on my site using Google viewer. Document url I get from blob, but when I click to show docs I had an error.
In console I see this link: blob:http://localhost:8080/5372d78d-a9c6-4c50-b23b-249cc643bdd2

````
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([response.data], { type: response.data.type })
      );
        const link = document.createElement("iframe");
        console.log(url);
        link.src = `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${url}&embedded=true`;
        link.style.width = "100%";
        link.style.height = "500px";
        document.getElementById(fileId).appendChild(link);
    },```

```async showDoc(file) {
      this.fileId = file.Document.Id;
      this.fileName = file.Document.Name;
     
        try {
          let response = await axios.get(url, {
            responseType: "blob",
            params: {
              fileId: this.fileId,
            },
          });
          this.forceFileShow(response, this.fileId);
          console.log("удача", response);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("неудача", err.response);
        }
      }
    }, 

And here html:
<div class="card-icon" @click="showDoc(file)"
        :data-target="`#showDoc${file.Document.Id}`"
         data-toggle="modal">```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZlkm.png
````